# Copy axes instance

Tags: python, matplotlib

Short explanation: I want to copy the data and properties of a certain Axes-instance to another Axes instance, with the difference that I want to zoom in to a certain region.

Long explanation: I am using a third-party software, astLib, to create a plot like the on shown on their homepage: http://astlib.sourceforge.net/.  What I now want to do is to make an ImageGrid which zooms into different regions of this plot, but maintaining the labels (I don't need to adjust the ticks, only zoom in). I can maybe copy the information of the labels, but the astLib package does some clipping and scaling to the data and I have no clue how to copy that information.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the easiest way would be to take the original image, clipImageSectionPix as you need, scales it with scaleImage and then create a new plot - the axes and labels should then be created, correctly and automatically for then new FOV, (you will even get the ticks adjusted).

Comment: I don't see where the new axes and labels are created, unless you mean to replot them with ImagePlot. In that case it is still impossible to create multiple axes instances to zoom in different regions.